# Vanilla Javascript for loop to remove html elements from selected collection

Tags: javascript, html

```
var overrideField = document.querySelectorAll('.form_style_override_field');

overrideField.forEach(function (e) {
   e.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
});
```

I am trying to learn vanilla javascript and trying to remove an element which is pulled by classname.

```
var overrideField = document.getElementsByClassName('form_style_override_field');

  for (var i = 0; i < overrideField.length; i++)
  {
     var controlGroup = overrideField[i].parentNode.parentNode; 
     controlGroup.remove();
  }
```

```js
var overrideField = document.getElementsByClassName('form_style_override_field');

for (var i = 0; i < overrideField.length; i++)
{
   var controlGroup = overrideField[i].parentNode.parentNode;
   controlGroup.remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane active show" id="general">                           
 <div class="control-group">
  <div class="control-label">Label 1</div>
  <div class="controls">
    <span class="form_style_override_field"></span>         
    Control Group 1
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="control-group">
  <div class="control-label">Label 2</div>
  <div class="controls">
    <span class="form_style_override_field"></span>
    Control Group 2
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The overrideField variable sees 2 elements and it will only remove the last one. Can anyone help me figure it out please.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example that reproduces the error?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] by posting your HTML and JavaScript in the 4 paneled editor by clicking the bracket button: `<>`

Comment: @mhodges I added a snippet, it remove the first element in an array rather than the last one as I mentioned above. Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a live collection, so when you remove an element in your for loop the collection (and length) changes so your loop never gets to the last element. Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead to return a static collection and then remove the elements.

For example:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.class-to-remove');
elems.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.remove();
});
```

Comment: didn't knew querySelectorAll, really. Thanks.

I've created a jsfiddle to try it out https://jsfiddle.net/celerno/n0q425t1/

Comment: Awesome! Yes, querySelectorAll worked. Thank you for the solution and explaining getElementByClassName behavior.