# Modify a list of HTML elements in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I've got a problem with access to a html collection in JavaScript.

Here is the link to my project : [Codepen](https://codepen.io/s4mking/pen/WLoLzx)

At the line 136 to 154 I add an eventListener to a button for remove all the li with a button with same Class than the first button ID. Sorry for the explain it's a but messy. My question here is for the loop:

```
for (var k = 0; k < listeDelLength.length; k++) {
    var pars = listeClassDelete[k];
    pars.parentNode.removeChild(pars); 
    //k--;
}
```

My loop works 2 by 2, I know that's because I remove my own object inside the loop. I've tried to access just the object length, to push like the example above inside an array but there is still a connection between the two. The only solution I've find is to add a k-- to iterate on all element.
have you a solution please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you want to accomplish. Is it that you want to iterate over that list without it skipping an element each time?

Comment: don't modify the original list, make a copy.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a live collection of HTML elements. If you're removing elements which are referred in the collection, the collection gets shorter, and you're jumping over some elements. Iterate backwards, or use `querySelectorAll` to get a static list.

Comment: Is 'boucle' supposed to be English? Please translate if possible.

Comment: @PeterB https://www.thefreedictionary.com/boucle = ).

Comment: When you delete a row, the index of the next row will have changed. The solution would be te loop your your rows backward. `for(var k = listeDelLength.length-1; k >=0 ; k--){`.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you very much for your help it solves my problem.

Comment: You can also solve this by selecting your elements with `querySelectorAll()`, see [Vanilla Javascript for loop to remove elements from selected collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51068352/vanilla-javascript-for-loop-to-remove-html-elements-from-selected-collection/51068763#51068763)